# Poner timeout a ejecución en bash lanzado en máquina remota vía SSH

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Quiero validar que puertos están abiertos/cerrados entre máquinas desde una central, para ello he creado una variable que guardará en una cadena indicando si el puerto está "open" o "closed":

```
CHECK_PORT=`ssh $origen "bash -c '</dev/$TIPOPUERTO/$destino/$puerto && echo open || echo closed'"`
```

El problema que tengo es que al lanzar el comando a través de ssh si el puerto está cerrado el script se queda esperando a que haya timeout.

¿Cómo podría ponerle un timeout a esta ejecución?

Comment: Nótese que es mucho más seguro decir `var=$(comando)`. Los backticks ``` no permiten anidaciones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactamente [`timeout`](https://ss64.com/bash/timeout.html) es lo que estás buscando.

Por ejemplo, esto ejecuta un `sleep 5` y lo hace terminar en 1 segundo:

```
timeout 1 sleep 5 || echo "no acaba"
```

Como no consigue terminar `sleep 5`, se ejecuta el `echo "no acaba"`.

Ahora bien, el comando [`ssh`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) tiene una opción que permite hacer el timeout directamente:

```
-o ConnectTimeout=XX  # XX en segundos
```

Por lo que podrías decir:

```
ssh $origen -o ConnectTimeout=XX "bash -c '</dev/$TIPOPUERTO/$destino/$puerto && echo open || echo closed'
```

Comment: Me ha funcionado sin problemas a la hora de ejecutarlo en el servidor local, lo que cuando lo ejecuto mediante ssh (en commandline):

`ssh -o ConnecTtimeout=3 -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no origen "timeout 1 bash -c '</dev/tcp/destino/22 && echo open || echo closed'"`

Aparece:

bash: timeout: command not found

Y si lo hago mediante script, la sesión se queda "bloqueada".

Comment: @David si usas `ConnectTimeout` (tienes un error en la sintaxis) no hace falta poner el timeout en el comando.